# The hard way to debug the mysterious git+ssh+proxy failure "bash: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, bash, ssh, exec

I'm trying to clone a github repo via a SOCKS5 proxy. In `~/.ssh/config` I have:

```
Host github.com *.github.com
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 %h %p
```

`git clone` fails with error `bash: No such file or directory`:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:aureliojargas/sedsed.git
Cloning into 'sedsed'...
bash: No such file or directory
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I manually tried the `ssh` command and it also fails:

```
$ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pynexj/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/pynexj/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 github.com 22
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
bash: No such file or directory
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pynexj/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Then I manually tried the `nc` command and it actually works:

```
$ /usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 github.com 22
SSH-2.0-babeld-8cd15329
^C
```

And the SOCKS5 proxy works fine too:

```
$ curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:7070/ https://github.com/ > foo.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  214k    0  214k    0     0  86775      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 86775
```

I'm very curious about who (and why) produces the error `bash: no such file or directory`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the issue is macOS specific. I Googled a lot and found many broken SSH cases on macOS 10.15 (Catalina) but none of the workarounds works for me. Eventually I had to take a look at the OpenSSH code and found out the issue.

---

In source file [sshconnect.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshconnect.c):

```
 194 static int
 195 ssh_proxy_connect(struct ssh *ssh, const char *host, const char *host_arg,
 196     u_short port, const char *proxy_command)
 197 {
 ...
 ...
 201     char *shell;
 202
 203     if ((shell = getenv("SHELL")) == NULL || *shell == '\0')
 204         shell = _PATH_BSHELL;
 ...
 ...
 211     command_string = expand_proxy_command(proxy_command, options.user,
 212         host, host_arg, port);
 213     debug("Executing proxy command: %.500s", command_string);
 214
 215     /* Fork and execute the proxy command. */
 216     if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
 217         char *argv[10];
 ...
 ...
 240         argv[0] = shell;
 241         argv[1] = "-c";
 242         argv[2] = command_string;
 243         argv[3] = NULL;
 244
 245         /* Execute the proxy command.  Note that we gave up any
 246            extra privileges above. */
 247         ssh_signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL);
 248         execv(argv[0], argv);
 249         perror(argv[0]);
 250         exit(1);
 251     }
```

See line 203, 240 and 248, ssh is trying to run the *ProxyCommand* with `$SHELL` <sup>(I found no doc for this)</sup> and it's using [execv()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) which would not search in `$PATH`. Then I checked my `$SHELL`:

```
$ echo $SHELL
bash
```

So that's the problem. `$SHELL` is not a full pathname executable so `execv()` failed to execute it and the error `bash: No such file or directory` is from [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) in line 249. <sup>(The error confused me a lot. The prefix `bash:` made me think the error is from Bash.)</sup>

**SOLUTION:** Manually set `SHELL` to the shell's full pathname, e.g. `/bin/bash`. <sup>(I did not write `shell /bin/bash` in `.screenrc` because I also has `/usr/local/bin/bash`.)</sup>

---

Then who sets `SHELL=bash`? Why doesn't it set `SHELL=/bin/bash`?

In my `~/.screenrc` I have:

```
shell bash
```

According to screen [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html):

> - *shell* command
>
>   Set the command to be used to create a new shell.  **This overrides the value of the environment variable `$SHELL`**.

The `SHELL` var is initially `/bin/bash` in my interactive shell before I started screen so it's screen who set `SHELL=bash`. I think screen should find out the full pathname of the shell and set `SHELL` to the full pathname, because, according to [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> This variable shall represent a **pathname** of the user's preferred command language interpreter.

---

Then why it works all fine on my Linux system (Debian) where I have `SHELL=bash` too (also in screen)?

I did a [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and got this:

```
$ SHELL=xxx strace -f ssh git@github.com
[...]
[pid  5767] rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
[pid  5767] execve("/root/bin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] execve("/usr/local/bin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] execve("/usr/local/sbin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] execve("/usr/sbin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] execve("/usr/bin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] execve("/sbin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] execve("/bin/xxx", ["xxx", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x561e33a599a0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5767] dup(2)                      = 3
[pid  5767] fcntl(3, F_GETFL)           = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  5767] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x21), ...}) = 0
[pid  5767] write(3, "xxx: No such file or directory\n", 31xxx: No such file or directory
) = 31
[pid  5767] close(3)                    = 0
[...]
```

As we can see, it's actually searching `xxx` in `$PATH`. Why? I guess Debian must have patched openssh and changed its behavior. <sup>(I would have verified this if I know Debian build internals. :-)</sup>

---

**UPDATE 2020-11-19**:

I manually compiled OpenSSH (v8.4) from [source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable) and reproduced the same issue on Debian. This confirms Debian has patched OpenSSH and changed its behavior.

```
$ /usr/local/openssh-8.4/bin/ssh git@github.com
bash: No such file or directory
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
$ strace -f /usr/local/openssh-8.4/bin/ssh git@github.com
[...]
[pid 21020] rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a05a9840}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
[pid 21020] execve("bash", ["bash", "-c", "exec nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7070 g"...], 0x5566982872f0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21020] dup(2)                      = 3
[pid 21020] fcntl(3, F_GETFL)           = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid 21020] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x25), ...}) = 0
[pid 21020] write(3, "bash: No such file or directory\n", 32bash: No such file or directory
) = 32
[pid 21020] close(3)
[...]
```