# Lost access to github after upgrading to Catalina (MAC OS)

Tags: bash, git, macos, ssh

I upgraded Catalina, then I lost access to my github repo:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

```
$ ssh -vvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/XXX/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/XXX/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/XXX/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This used to work fine. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Is your public key still the same and in your GitHub account?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Connecting to ssh.github.com port 443
> ```

That means you are [Using SSH over the HTTPS port](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)

Try instead the test:

```
ssh -Tv -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

But double-check to that port 22 is blocked:

```
ssh -T -p 22 git@github.com
```

If this still fails, check out "[The hard way to debug the mysterious git+ssh+proxy failure “bash: No such file or directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64893356/6309)"

> Solution: Manually set `SHELL` to the shell's full pathname, e.g. `/bin/bash`.

Comment: not sure if it's the same issue as mine. the error is different.

Comment: @pynexj Still, it is worth checking it out.